# How to represent the kinetic equation in syntax

Tags: c++, function, equation, cmath

So i'd like to write the formula

```
KE = 1 / 2mv^2
```

in C++, creating a function that calculates a value using the kinetic energy equation. But I'm not entirely 
sure how to go about showing `1 / 2`. Wouldn't I have to make it a `double` because if I represent `1 / 2` as an integer it'll just display `5`? What the compiler is really seeing would be `0.5`, from which the zero is cut off? Here is the piece of code I have so far to calculating this equation: double KE = 1/2*m*v*pow(KE,2); Here's my code and what i'm trying to do.

It's giving me `0` instead of `25` when I use the test values of `2` and `5`.

```
//my protyped function kineticEnergy
double kineticEnergy(int m, int v);

    int main(){
      int m; // needed to pass a value into kineticEnergy function
      int v; // needed to pass a value into kineticEnergy function

      cout << "Enter the mass " << endl;
      cin >> m;
      cout << "Enter the velocity" << endl;
      cin >> v;
      int results = kineticEnergy(m,v);

      cout << "The total kinetic energy of the object is " << results << endl;

      return 0;
    } // end of main

    // ##########################################################
    //
    //  Function name: kineticEnergy
    //
    //  Description:This will grab input from a program and calculate
    // kinetic energy within the function
    // ##########################################################

    double kineticEnergy(int m, int v){
      double KE = 1/2*m*v*pow(KE,2); // equation for calculating kinetic energy

        return KE;
    } // end of kinetic energy
```

Comment: Perhaps you should first read a book about computing C++ basics.

Comment: write `0.5 * ...` instead. And follow @Walter's advice.

Comment: When does `1/2` ever evaluate to `5`??

Comment: `if I represent 1 / 2 as an integer it'll just display 5?` No it will not it will display 0. Before you ask for help read a book or even a website about the fundamentals of C++ and programming in general

Comment: Apart from the problem with 1/2 and integers-doubles, which is the object of the question and so it's ok, your formula is wrong. Why are you using `pow(KE,2)`? As noted by user4581301, KE is not even initialised here. You don't want `KE`, you want `v`. So it's either `double KE = 1/2*m*v*v;` or `double KE = 1/2*m*pow(v,2);`.

Comment: For your information Jack William's, I have already taken a college programming course in java and right now i'm currently taking a programming class in c++. And before I even started taking college programming courses. I was studying c++ without fear second edition by Brian overland and I also was referencing the website tutorial point as I still am referencing that website along with coding made easy, and buckys you tube.

Comment: And wow, okay I completely did not see that! The formula for calculating kinetic energy is "k = m*v^2" I was looking into how to use pow() in cmath. When pow() said base my mind right away was thinking KE was the base.

Comment: don't use `std::pow` for computing low-integer powers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, 1 and 2 are integer constants, so `1/2` gives you `0`, which is the result of the integral division of 1 by 2.

What you want is this (assuming "`m*v*pow(KE,2)`" is correct):

```
double KE = 1.0/2.0*m*v*pow(KE,2);
```

Comment: "assuming `m*v*pow(KE,2)` is correct." Don't be so coy. Of course it isn't. `KE` is used uninitialized.

Comment: @user4581301 you're right, my bad. This part was formated badly in the original post and I didn't catch it after it was corrected.

Answer (score 2):

using `std::array<double,3>` for the velocity vector:

```
double kinetic_energy(double mass, std::array<double,3> const&velocity)
{
  return 0.5 * mass * (velocity[0]*velocity[0]+
                       velocity[1]*velocity[1]+
                       velocity[2]*velocity[2]); 
}
```

Note 1) that the velocity is a vector (whose magnitude is the speed) and 2) using `std::pow()` cannot be recommended for computing the square: its much more computationally costly than a single multiplication (with C++11). You may want to use the auxiliary

```
inline double square(double x)
{ return x*x; }
```

and then

```
double kinetic_energy(double mass, std::array<double,3> const&velocity)
{
  return 0.5 * mass * (square(velocity[0])+square(velocity[1])+square(velocity[2])); 
}
```

Comment: Finally! A valid proof that it's hip to be square!

Answer (score 0):

The best one could do is this-

It took me 4 hours to devise, modify and simplify this answer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int m;
cout << "Enter mass (in kg): ";
cin >> m;

int v;
cout << "Enter velocity (in m/s): ";
cin >> v;

cout << "If mass is " << m << " kg" << endl;
cout << "and velocity is " << v << " m/s," << endl;

float kinEn = m * pow(v,2) * (0.5);
cout << "then kinetic energy is " << kinEn << " Joules" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Avoid making it a function
and mostly try to first declare, then write what is it about (using cout) and then to provide space for entering the value (using cin).

The code gives the following result.

```
 Enter mass (in kg): 
 Enter velocity (in m/s): 
 If mass is 57 kg
 and velocity is 20 m/s,
 then kinetic energy is 11400 Joules
```

Comment: This works fine, but the reason yours works and OP's doesn't is because you used the correct equation for the kinetic energy and multiplied by a float (instead of multiplying by two integers divided, which didn't give the expected result). Both of these points have already been made to OP, and are contained in the accepted answer. Please only add answers to questions when they add something new. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).